# Reduce size of set of sets through unions, restricted by maximum union size

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I have a set of distinct sets, where none of the distinct sets have more than `k` elements. E.g. with `k` of `4`:

```
set([frozenset({0, 3, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 1, 2}),
     frozenset({6, 7}),
     frozenset({8, 7}),
     frozenset({1, 2}),
     frozenset({9, 11, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({0, 11, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({9, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({11, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({0, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({0, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 3, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({11}),
     frozenset({8}),
     frozenset({8, 6, 7}),
     frozenset({0, 1, 3, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 1, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 1}),
     frozenset({3, 4, 5}),
     frozenset({9, 6}),
     frozenset({9, 10}),
     frozenset({4, 5}),
     frozenset({11, 9, 3, 6}),
     frozenset({9, 11, 6}),
     frozenset({9, 3, 6}),
     frozenset({3, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 9, 3, 6}),
     frozenset({10}),
     frozenset({9, 10, 6}),
     frozenset({0, 3, 4, 6}),
     frozenset({3, 4, 6}),
     frozenset({3, 4}),
     frozenset({11, 6})])
```

I want to unite the frozen sets with each other to make the amount of entries in the surrounding set as small as possible. However, the aforementioned condition that no set may have a size greater than `k` must remain true. If I were to brute force this, this would be doable <s>in O(n³) time (oof)</s> in O(n!) time (oooof). Depending on the order in which one matches possible unions one can create states where the correct solution can no longer be reached.

E.g.: If given `{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}` with a limit of 3 elements per set I were to unite `{1, 3}` and `{3, 4}` this would yield `{1, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}`. Had I instead united `{3, 4}` and `{3, 5}`, I would have gotten `{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}` and then `{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}` (one set less).

I see no obvious strategy here. In the example, all 4 initially available sets have the same size and except for `{1, 2}` and `{3, 4}` they all share exactly one element between each other. So: how do I reduce the size of a set of sets through unions of the inner sets as much as possible, while having the inner sets not exceed a given size?

EDIT 1: I was able to write a function which eliminates subsets in O(n²), which is a good start.

```py
def uniteSetsWithSupersets(s: set) -> set:
    t = set()
    for k in s:
        for l in t:
            if k.issubset(l) or l.issubset(k):
                t.remove(l)
                t.add(k.union(l))
                break
        else:
            t.add(k)
    return t
```

Comment: How would you brute force this in cubic time?

Comment: Comparing each set to every other set is `(n²-n)/2` steps, so O(n²). Every time you do so, you take away only one entry. So you do an operation that is O(n²) about n times, aka O(n³). Am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct that there are N choose 2 pairs to consider. And you are correct that after combining two sets into one, `n` is reduced by 1. But the missing part is the decision algorithm. How do you choose which sets to combine? The brute force algorithm would try every possible legal pair, resulting in factorial complexity.

Comment: The approach I would take is to look for the least common numbers, and work on those first. In the second example, 3 is the most common number, 1 is the second most common number, and 2,4,5 are the least common numbers. So the set to start with is `{1,2}`. That set can only be combined with `{1,3}`. That gives two choices, either keep `{1,2}` or create the union `{1,2,3}`. The latter happens to be correct, but the code would have to try both.

Comment: In the first example (with the `frozenset`s) the problem is easy to solve, because after removing strict subsets, there are no legal moves remaining, i.e. no pair of sets can be combined without exceeding the maximum set size of 4.

Comment: I think the aspect of dictionary, and frozenset is not very relevant to the question. This could just be about sets. If you have the solution for sets, it is easy to apply to your specific data structure. This question would be more useful for future visitors if it would just be about sets. I would advise to edit your question towards that goal.

Comment: Do you have more information about the size of constraints- number of sets, total number of unique elements, and maximum set size?

Comment: @kcsquared Unique elements (the numbers) can potentially be in the 100s, but not 1000s. `k` is unlikely to ever be larger than `8`. Amount of sets will generally be between 2 to 4 times the amount of elements. An element is unlikely to appear in more than 15 sets, usually in less than 7.

Comment: This problem seems likely to be NP-hard, as it is closely related to set covering. For example, just the question of whether we can find `n` sets whose union has at most `k` unique elements is [NP-complete and a generalization of the clique problem.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33146/bipartite-graphs-maximum-subset-of-one-partition-with-at-most-n-neighbours-n?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this had a simple solution. So here is an outline of a pragmatic approach that could work depeding on the size of your inputs.

Start with a slight modification. Say that we are looking for a smallest "cover" collection of sets `c_1`, ..., `c_n` (each of size <= `k`) such that every given set `s_i` is a subset of one or more cover sets.

Find all the candidates to be in the cover. For that take repeated unions of given sets `s_i` with each other and save all possible results of cardinality less than `k`.

Then formulate a constraint programming problem. Assign an indicator variable to each of the candidates. For each `s_i` add a constraint, specifying that the sum of the variables corresponding to candidates containing it add to more than 1. Add a minimisation target over the sum of the indicator variables. Solve. `ortools` can handle this (https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html)

Finally modify the solution, and remove some unnecessary elements from the cover sets (if there are any).